# Hide Survey Time Created & Number of Responses

Tags: javascript, survey, classic-experience

[image]

Hi, I am very new to SharePoint. I do not have any coding background.

I created a survey as shown in the photo. However, I am trying to hide the two columns:

- Time Created
- Number of Responses

Appreciate if I can get guided steps on how to hide the 2 columns.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using? Do you have access to Script Editor or Content Editor webpart on your site/survey page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to **Script Editor** or **Content Editor** webpart then you can try adding below code to your Survey page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function runAfterEverythingElse(){
        document.querySelector("td[id^='overview03']").parentElement.style.display = "none";
        document.querySelector("td[id^='overview04']").parentElement.style.display = "none";
    }
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("runAfterEverythingElse");
</script>
```

Check below references to find out how to use the Script Editor webpart in SharePoint.

**References**:

1. [Script Editor Web Part in SharePoint 2016/2013/Online](https://www.spguides.com/script-editor-web-part-sharepoint-2016/)
2. [How to Use the Script Editor Web Part in SharePoint 2013](https://bamboosolutions.com/blog/how-to-use-script-editor-web-part-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: Thank you sir! This worked like a charm!

Comment: Great... Glat it worked for you. Please [Upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you.